# @OneToMany pulling all related fields except foreign key

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have a Demographics entity that contains a Collection of MedicalRecordsReceived entities:

`//Demographics entity`

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "demographics", fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Collection medicalRecordsReceivedCollection;

and

`//MedicalRecordsReceived entity`

@JoinColumn(name = "demographics_id", referencedColumnName = "iddemographics")
@ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
private Demographics demographics;

When I pull a Demographics entity (to my Struts App) the Collection comes along fine and all fields in each MedicalRecordsReceived entity displays fine except the id of the Demographics entity held in the MedicalRecordsReceived table which is the foreign key of course. The same problem is occurring when persisting. Foreign key cant be found and updates don't occur.

I do realize I already have the foreign key when I pull the Demographics entity but wondering why I cant get at through the Demographics entity getters. I guess I am not fully understanding the circular relationship here...

Nick

Answer (score 0):

You can't map the same database column to two different fields. The `demographics_id` join column is already used to map the demographics ManyToOne association. To get the value of the foreign key, just use `medicalRecordsReceived.getDemographics().getId()`.

To persist a new MedicalRecordsReceived instance pointing to a Demographics  instance, you have to initialize the association (and maintain the reverse association to have a coherent object model) :

```
MedicalRecordsReceived m = new MedicalRecordsReceived();
m.setDemographics(demographics);
demographics.getMedicalRecordsReceivedCollection().add(m);
// the cascade will take care of the persistence of m
```

Think in terms of objects, not in terms of columns.

Comment: Just curious how the demographics_id column is mapped to two fields? This field exists in the MedicalRecordsRecieved table and holds the primary key of the Demographics object. It is only referenced directly in the mapping of the MedicalRecordsReceived. The Demographics mapping defers to the MedicalRecordsReceived for the mapping. Thanks.